# How do you mock a RelatedManager method in Django?

Tags: django, testing, mocking

I have a customer manager for a Django model which overrides the `create` method to also save some related objects:

```
class CustomManager(models.Manager):
    def create(self, amount, user, description):
        txn = self.get_query_set().create(user, description)
        txn.budget_transactions.create(amount)
        return txn
```

My question is: how do I mock the call to `txn.budget_transactions.create` to raise an exception?

The `budget_transactions` attribute of the `txn` object is an instance of `django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager`.  Using `mock.patch` to mock this class doesn't work as it is declared dynamically - it can't be imported directly.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Are you using Mock library? Do you want to use a patch context-manager or a decorator?

Comment: I'm happy to use the mock library if it can solve this problem.  As I state above, using `mock.patch` in the conventional way doesn't work due to the dynamic declaration of RelatedManager classes.

Answer (score 10):

The reason that you can't just set the RelatedManager to a mock object is because django has overridden the **set** method on the object. So while it appears that the mock is getting set correctly because there are no complaints, it's actually silently setting `budget_transactions` back to the RelatedManager. So if you really need to return a mock then you'll need to override the **get** method that returns the RelatedManager and return a mocked object instead.

Should end up lookig somthing like:

```
@mock.patch('django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor.__get__')
def test_campaign_cancel(self, mock_manager):
    mock_manager.return_value = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_manager.return_value.create = Exception('Boom!')
```

That being said there are many pitfalls to this approach since it will be overriding a core django method and now *ALL* RelatedManagers will return a mocked object. From what I have experienced so far it's probably easier to explore other options.

Comment: I had to mock `django.db.models.fields.related.ReverseManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor.__set__`, but same general approach.

Comment: A contemporary answer to this question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55910709/2407209

Answer (score 2):

`RelatedManager` is a descriptor and has to be mocked using [`unittest.PropertyMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock)

```py
from unittest import patch, MagicMock, PropertyMock, TestCase


class CustomManagerTest(TestCase):
    @patch('app.managers.Transaction.budget_transactions', new_callable=PropertyMock)
    def test_custom_manager_create(self, mock_budget_transactions):
        mock_create = MagicMock()
        mock_budget_transaction.return_value.create = mock_create

        self.assertEqual(mock_create.call_count, 1)
```