# Mocking a RelatedManager in Django 2

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, pytest, python-mock, pytest-django

This question is directly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212786/how-do-you-mock-a-relatedmanager-method-in-django), but that one is now outdated it seems.

I am trying to test a view without having to access the database. To do that I need to Mock a `RelatedManager` on the user.

I am using `pytest` and `pytest-mock`.

models.py

```
# truncated for brevity, taken from django-rest-knox
class AuthToken(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        null=False, 
        blank=False,
        related_name='auth_token_set', 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

views.py

```
class ChangeEmail(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAdmin]
    serializer_class = serializers.ChangeEmail

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        user = request.user
        user.email = request.validated_data['email']
        user.save()

        # Logout user from all devices
        user.auth_token_set.all().delete() # <--- How do I mock this?

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

test_views.py

```
def test_valid(mocker, user_factory):
    user = user_factory.build()
    user.id = 1

    data = {
        'email': 'foo@example.com'
    }

    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    request = factory.post('/', data=data)
    force_authenticate(request, user)

    mocker.patch.object(user, "save")

    related_manager = mocker.patch(
        'django.db.models.fields.related.ReverseManyToOneDescriptor.__set__',
        return_vaue=mocker.MagicMock()
    )
    related_manager.all = mocker.MagicMock()
    related_manager.all.delete = mocker.MagicMock()

    response = ChangeEmail.as_view()(request)
    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
```

Drawing from the answer in the linked question I tried to patch the `ReverseManyToOneDescriptor`. However, it does not appear to actually get mocked because the test is still trying to connect to the database when it tries to delete the user's `auth_token_set`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to mock the return value of the `create_reverse_many_to_one_manager` factory function. Example:

```
def test_valid(mocker):
    mgr = mocker.MagicMock()
    mocker.patch(
        'django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager', 
        return_value=mgr
    )

    user = user_factory.build()
    user.id = 1
    ...
    mgr.assert_called()
```

Beware that the above example will mock the rev manager for all models. If you need a more fine-grained approach (e.g. patch `User.auth_token`'s rev manager only, leave the rest unpatched), provide a custom factory impl, e.g.

```
def test_valid(mocker):
    mgr = mocker.MagicMock()
    factory_orig = related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager
    def my_factory(superclass, rel):
        if rel.model == User and rel.name == 'auth_token_set':
            return mgr
        else:
            return factory_orig(superclass, rel)

    mocker.patch(
        'django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager',
        my_factory
    )

    user = user_factory.build()
    user.id = 1
    ...
    mgr.assert_called()
```

Comment: Wow, that is awesome! Thank you for figuring that out

Answer (score 2):

I accomplish this doing this(Django 1.11.5)

```
@patch("django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors.create_reverse_many_to_one_manager")
def test_reverse_mock_count(self, reverse_mock):
    instance = mommy.make(DjangoModel)

    manager_mock = MagicMock
    count_mock = MagicMock()
    manager_mock.count = count_mock()
    reverse_mock.return_value = manager_mock

    instance.related_manager.count()
    self.assertTrue(count_mock.called)
```

hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

If you use django's `APITestCase`, this becomes relatively simple.

```
class TestChangeEmail(APITestCase):
    def test_valid(self):
        user = UserFactory()
        auth_token = AuthToken.objects.create(user=user)

        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('your endpoint'), 
            data={'email': 'foo@example.com'}
        )

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertFalse(AuthToken.objects.filter(user=user).exists())
```

This avoids mocking altogether and gives a more accurate representation of your logic.

Comment: Thank you for writing. However, I want to test without using the database. That is why I am using mocker to patch the database calls. That is the purpose of the question. Also I am using a `RequestFactory` instead of the `client` to test the view directly. I can successfully test with db access.

Comment: Here is a simple blog post explaining why to write unit tests w/o db access. https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/07/27/faster-django-view-unit-tests-with-mocks.html#

Comment: And here is an explanation as to why to not use the `client`. Cheers. https://www.ianlewis.org/en/testing-django-views-without-using-test-client

Comment: @pymarco quoting the first post you cited, _In my opinion, mocking out the database layer is silly; we already have an abstraction for that, it's called the ORM. Instead, you can get all the speed you need by using an in memory sqlite3 database for your unit tests._ While using `RequestFactory` over `Client` indeed makes sense in some scenarios (e.g. middleware testing), I've never seen a use case that would require mocking the ORM layer.

Comment: @hoefling thanks for pointing out that contradiction. I was going fast and overlooked it. My initial thought is one of concern since Django offers a lot of Postgres specific functionality. I will now consider sqlite, but need to do so cautiously. It doesn't seem _silly_ to mock the ORM to me b/c I know the ORM works so it makes sense to control it's output during a test.

Comment: After thinking about it some more, and reading around for the last hour, I feel more confident testing with Postgres if I'm going to use db access. If speed does become an issue as I expand out then I'll readdress. That is, unless someone is able to show how to patch the `RelatedManager`.

Answer (score 1):

[`unittest.PropertyMock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock) can be used to mock descriptors in a way that doesn't require mocking internal implementation details:

```py
def test_valid(mocker, user_factory):
    user = user_factory.build()
    user.id = 1

    data = {
        'email': 'foo@example.com'
    }

    factory = APIRequestFactory()
    request = factory.post('/', data=data)
    force_authenticate(request, user)

    mocker.patch.object(user, "save")

    with mocker.patch('app.views.User.auth_token_set', new_callable=PropertyMock) as mock_auth_token_set:
        mock_delete = mocker.MagicMock()
        mock_auth_token_set.return_value.all.return_value.delete = mock_delete

        response = ChangeEmail.as_view()(request)

    assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK
    assert mock_delete.call_count == 1
```

Comment: This seems to be the most "pytestic" way.